# Checking Certificate Signature

Tags: tls, certificates, digital-signature

Here's my problem: I'm trying to enable HTTPS on a local site for learning reasons. The thing is, I don't want to generate the certificate with some well-known application, but i want to create a homemade one. I made a self signed certificate because I don't need any chain of trust.

The .crt I made:

```
$ openssl x509 -in server.crt -text
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            06:31:4c:1a:04:d2:19:e4:eb:6c:a7:6f:47:74:63:67:b4:ac
    Signature Algorithm: rsassaPss
         Hash Algorithm: sha256
         Mask Algorithm: mgf1 with sha256
         Salt Length: 0x20
         Trailer Field: 0x01
        Issuer: C=FR, ST=Aquitaine, L=Bordeaux, O=Cyebrens, OU=Cyberens Test, CN=192.168.2.149
        Validity
            Not Before: Apr  6 12:36:16 2018 GMT
            Not After : Apr  6 12:36:16 2019 GMT
        Subject: C=FR, ST=Aquitaine, L=Bordeaux, O=Cyebrens, OU=Cyberens Test, CN=192.168.2.149
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:8c:7c:3c:68:f6:0d:d1:eb:64:df:a2:4d:1a:0b:
                    65:6c:27:15:c3:a5:33:3e:59:78:63:c3:21:62:6c:
                    73:35:dc:ff:02:8f:b8:d8:01:7f:97:4d:a3:90:8e:
                    3d:90:49:af:65:12:66:19:e7:35:1d:ee:de:ee:98:
                    8f:68:12:6d:6c:fc:a6:41:bd:72:f6:39:dd:55:63:
                    50:98:e5:d9:72:3d:32:55:5b:ca:21:1a:97:3c:af:
                    bb:85:1c:32:a2:dc:7c:ae:48:15:5a:ad:f9:00:47:
                    16:89:b9:14:30:85:06:cb:1e:80:c7:ec:5c:d4:d5:
                    72:90:37:67:4b:70:0c:2f:05:ae:de:1b:2c:cb:9c:
                    3a:93:2c:5e:54:8b:72:67:42:eb:b9:dc:bd:83:e8:
                    cd:40:55:17:4a:59:08:80:6e:81:e7:74:e5:70:47:
                    40:d9:d3:d5:d2:77:7b:8f:84:d9:18:75:ea:d3:f3:
                    2c:f1:8a:8a:bf:40:0a:c1:1c:4f:52:41:31:ca:93:
                    88:2f:31:68:52:59:4d:60:a1:14:e8:31:0f:db:54:
                    87:bd:27:1d:55:b5:fa:a4:98:24:06:f2:93:c4:85:
                    58:ec:57:7a:b9:8d:1b:1a:ef:9d:85:f8:df:89:29:
                    5c:2c:d3:32:42:15:75:14:4f:b9:36:33:fc:62:54:
                    47:13
                Exponent:
                    40:00:10:00:40:20:00:00:08:00:00:02:00:00:00:
                    00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:00:d7
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                01:02:06
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:01:02:06

            X509v3 Basic Constraints:
                CA:TRUE
    Signature Algorithm: rsassaPss
         Hash Algorithm: sha256
         Mask Algorithm: mgf1 with sha256
         Salt Length: 0x20
         Trailer Field: 0x01

         24:b8:30:d6:7e:49:a7:cc:a0:77:e1:b6:cd:37:70:18:74:1b:
         1f:17:61:a4:f7:47:22:f5:50:ee:e7:c8:4f:2c:55:a8:7a:e8:
         16:63:ae:28:72:ab:2e:b2:98:7c:c9:9f:6c:a6:22:94:04:7b:
         c6:f2:15:4e:9b:f1:b7:0f:9b:7d:d2:e4:b7:b0:0f:b6:7d:2e:
         f9:64:b7:ce:cf:bd:51:7e:ae:96:7e:54:2c:46:a3:8e:87:c6:
         09:cf:4b:f1:18:85:eb:7e:01:a1:71:9b:80:53:d1:ca:c6:a0:
         1c:c7:86:06:0b:9b:70:40:62:5d:49:13:82:1f:1f:34:36:4f:
         91:91:e0:e2:1b:b4:ab:4d:a9:5e:ff:f5:be:ec:e0:e9:62:6d:
         bf:9d:6a:45:66:19:f0:54:4a:83:e4:ca:21:d2:a7:0e:c1:33:
         ed:6f:bb:3c:d1:9f:0f:e2:19:18:a5:d9:be:61:c4:7c:cd:03:
         d0:fa:be:31:57:8e:59:45:f3:90:00:79:0e:eb:0e:61:94:e0:
         95:ca:8d:8d:9a:02:84:a1:26:23:b4:ca:57:43:a1:0f:79:0c:
         12:27:e9:9f:74:da:88:c0:ed:76:2d:36:60:e5:57:ee:b3:4b:
         04:2b:37:6a:4d:4e:f1:25:25:81:b1:68:84:f8:30:41:48:39:
         0e:c2:1e:63
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

and the .key:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvwIBAAKCAQEAjHw8aPYN0etk36JNGgtlbCcVw6UzPll4Y8MhYmxzNdz/Ao+4
2AF/l02jkI49kEmvZRJmGec1He7e7piPaBJtbPymQb1y9jndVWNQmOXZcj0yVVvK
IRqXPK+7hRwyotx8rkgVWq35AEcWibkUMIUGyx6Ax+xc1NVykDdnS3AMLwWu3hss
y5w6kyxeVItyZ0Lrudy9g+jNQFUXSlkIgG6B53TlcEdA2dPV0nd7j4TZGHXq0/Ms
8YqKv0AKwRxPUkExypOILzFoUllNYKEU6DEP21SHvScdVbX6pJgkBvKTxIVY7Fd6
uY0bGu+dhfjfiSlcLNMyQhV1FE+5NjP8YlRHEwIcAEAAEABAIAAACAAAAgAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAA1wKCAQEACqFAUPXhScdULAvgx1kSqb3j9BlACmEH+Vv5IE3lywD+
hOOEPrynLT/yNdszOk6u/UvKi8+hpyechnWhCZ9rZwIJ3ohZNaN5UCXK9CkU0PHS
sl4MbUhL71qRMnR7euGO36bOqrEB2P0b5SIf4o6V8hPtnp37JN8woI4CrGGfq7T6
3W5274PSCaDuDaOH9YUvP9qB/jxoYh6FjaeRrYrnkJ98PHWp8tGVxV5nyABQ8COH
F+9QrsUe7RUA67exXaRxQ2Jcrl92CjZY+2vGKkYHxp2HYdDh4B1fXP3M6iWfEunk
b1v4HnK2L0lrUIqjkP45sxGA4eRnyINl1pDi3Zkx3wKBgQDbLCKD8YPgVJPZSO0v
MNovh3GJNr+L9TJ4dIfKNb45tnPiOaJrAJY2hMju912N5OXvmt99TzggJQlCgMUa
fMgjhawyXuO7DUBDAbh1GYFjzfdJHRi9gwUqyfg9ESTiySJUg1eyJxmbmnayMB3f
+Me0aVbTaRyJ3aQmus+s/UAvzwKBgQCkF1D7wmJAydmm5Ha428e6xMUziWpPA6bQ
gYkoyxBJkLb/LfbPBsYqD/iG3hm5JTtltl/FtcclejgatdOKUz3vo5H7+j+G1xT6
IGSdTrUPW6YXafYHSaO01I9dT/1Q0+Y5o6ePRr4H4Cd8nHVDtEPASaQkPrI0SSut
18QL9ojhfQKBgQBbfT7kUuaDFoQLGPhLX2d18iT8Ju81KHUhGRZLCHkS8H9MiD4f
Xh08OJaRvgt/xmRArPJz28hCZztqokjT60abwbXNqC1AZawNuSiqQk7m2CZPCcnV
ApTWwB7beF9v8jN9hYBj3aKgkIZi1zJ2TWSteAJpkaH8PfzQdKLfi/ZZZQKBgQAB
whqd4GMHvDsUbVp7oclCutbb5huSUfpAW5P1z/LRztxMs4brMvkd1oqjhCOtkFcR
nIvZh5UjwSFyIzOTkD54h1YtyPBMWGKsaojnZsQ+bRoUw8uqVDu0AXEQCwUsb5Hj
JAgjxJ0YtaYspDQc5dxrkO7/0AEsS21gXC7IV/76IwKBgQB2BcMO4hK1Cuu/g5L7
R2F4Kdjnt/a88sfstEAWXQJAa4NMAst0egoH+JD78k8Cei99xkrC+rt2GFSr4fh5
HgbPBikTmPtC9C3n996W0KXg3CocG1xihvs1iQIvYbtLfzi3NBf6jlSCe3fhU8Uo
hp6GlXSB9sDgqS88rtx3yK+D0A==
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The problem is that I got a "SEC_ERROR_BAD_SIGNATURE" on Mozilla when I try to go on my site. I used a homemade implementation to sign it ([RSASSA-PSS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3447)), so the problem may come from my implementation.

But when I open the certificate by double clicking on it, the signature seems valid, otherwise I would have some message saying the certificate is corrupted.

So 2 questions:

1. How can I check that my signature is valid? I can't find any simple way to do that.
2. If the signature is valid, what is the problem?

Comment: A certificate can be in a valid format while having an invalid signature.

Comment: Just as an FYI, but if you ever have a question about a Live system, do NOT post your private keys online ;-)

Comment: Sure I know that. But my RSAPSS signature algorithm didn’t work at first and I knew it because of the corrupted message thing when double clicking on it. Now this message disappeared, and that lets me think that my algorithm is correct. This is the whole point of my question. How can I check that ?

Comment: I know for the private key, if I posted it, it’s because this key is not really used, as i said it is for learning reasons only.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43630158/verify-x-509-certificate-signature-and-validity-c-code ?

Comment: Can’t check now. The problem with most of this tools, is that they don’t check self signed certificate (at least for openssl). But I’ll take a look on them later, thanks !

Comment: To check its validity you might take a look at [BoarSSL](https://www.bearssl.org/boarssl.html), which [The Bear](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/655/thomas-pornin) wrote to test his own TLS library.

Comment: Why is your exponent so large?  I see 26328173356909017646426704447934393073839397504785168138864951511 in your certificate, whereas a value like 65537 is more typical...

Comment: `openssl verify` doesn't check self-signed by default, but 1.1.0 (the current release) has an option `-check_ss_sig` to do so (and it likes your cert).

Comment: Thanks to David, I tried to change my public exponent to 65537. And it worked, even with RSASA-PSS. I can't find a x509 RFC where it's said that the public exponent SHOULD be 65537, so I'm a bit confused. Does someone know something about that ?

Answer (score 3):

> I used a homemade implementation to sign it (RSASSA-PSS), so the problem may come from my implementation.

RSASSA-PSS is currently not supported by Firefox. See [this issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1088140) for more information.  If in doubt look at the `signature_algorithm` extension in the TLS 1.2 handshake where it advertises which algorithms are supported.

Comment: Sigalgs for 1.2 can't specify RSASSA-PSS, only RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5. 1.3 proposes to change this -- and to use only PSS for in-protocol RSA signatures -- but is not yet standard.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Sigalgs is for the signature of the handshake. Certificates can use other algorithms.

Comment: @Gilles: nope. rfc5246 7.4.2: If the client provided a "signature_algorithms" extension, then all
   certificates provided by the server MUST be signed by a
   hash/signature algorithm pair that appears in that extension. 1.3 draft-28 4.4.2.2 says almost the same, but it excludes anchor including selfsigned (which doesn't need to be verified) and allows server to try something else only if it cannot comply with client offer.

Comment: @Gilles: in addition to the comment from dave_thompson_085: TLS 1.3 (draft 28) adds a `signature_algorithms_cert` extension specifically designed to allow different algorithms for certificate validation than for the other signature operations and recommends TLS 1.2 clients to also look for this extension. Absent this extension `signature_algorithms` is used as before, i.e. for all use cases including certificate validation.